# Angular multiple controllers $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out $scopes within different controllers. I have read alot of topics but can't seem to find out why it's not working in my code.

What I want is a single-page application but it's a little complex (for me), having build it in plain old JS I want to convert it to angular but having trouble with $scope and multiple controllers.

When someoneclicks on 'Dongel' it shows the manuals for dongel.
When I click the top manual it goes to /dongel-start and should load 'secondController' to manage all the context and values for the dongel installation manual but I can't seem to acces the secondController $scope?

First of all my HTML I managed to work with ng-view and a $routeProvider

```
<div id="wrap">

<div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

My angular JS file contains the following:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("instructions", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'welcome-page.html',
            controller: 'productController'
        })

        .when('/dongel-start', {
            templateUrl: 'dongel-start.html',
            controller: 'secondController'
        })

});

app.controller('productController', function($scope) {

    $scope.products = [
    { 
    name: 'Dongel',
    image: 'images/dongel.png',
    manuals: [
        {
        name: 'Geen Verbinding?',
        value: 'dongel-start'
        },
        {
        name: 'Installatie',
        value: 'dongel-start'
        },
        {
        name: 'APN Controleren',
        value: 'dongel-apn'
        },
        {
        name: 'Saldo',
        value: 'dongel-saldo'
        }
    ],
    value: 'Dongel'
    },
    { 
    name: 'Mifi',
    image: 'images/mifirouter.png',
    manuals: [
        { 
        name: 'Geen Verbinding?',
        value:'mifi-start'
        },
        {
        name: 'APN Controleren',
        value: 'mifi-apn'
        },
        {
        name: 'Saldo',
        value: 'mifi-saldo'
        }
    ],
    value: 'Mifi'
    }
    ];

$scope.showManuals = function(s){
        $scope.current = s.name; /* changing value of current*/
};


});


app.controler('secondController', function($scope) {

    $scope.systems = [
        {
            name: 'Windows'
        },
        {
            name: 'Apple'
        }
        ];

});


})();
```

The first page is working fine and it takes the values of $scope.products
When I get to the second page:

```
    <h2>Kies een besturingssysteem</h2>

    <ul style="height:100px;">
        <li ng-repeat="system in systems">
        {{system.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I am trying to acces the variables again but nothing shows up tough I have assigned 'secondController' to this page somehow $scope doesn't do the same as the first page.

The result on the 2nd page only shows the title which I have typed in manually..
I can't seem to acces

```
{{system.name}}
```

I would make a fiddle but it doesn't support routing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in secondController definition. You have there app.controler, which obviously does not make a controller out of the secondController but sth else.

Comment: Yes, wow thanks... I feel so stupid ^_^.

Btw, is this a proper way to setup functionallity in a single paged-layout? some directional tips?

Comment: I don't see anything bad in your design. Good stuff, for my eyes.

Comment: look at angular style guide by John papa https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: And while developing, definitely keep open your browser's developer tools!